# adding a hover div on an event in fullcalendar.js

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

i am using **fullcalendar.js** in my project what i want to do is show a div on hover of any event inside that div i have three action buttons edit,view,delete let me show you my code

**HTML**

```
 <div id="calendar"/>
```

**JavaScript/Jquery**

```
<script>
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
                },
                eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                    $template="<div class='hover-div clearfix' id='event_"+event.id+"'>"+
                        "<div class='display-inline-block'>"+
                        "<i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i>"+
                        "<a class='edit-calender common-font-properties'>Edit</a>"+
                        "</div>"+
                        "<div class='display-inline-block'>"+
                        "<i class='fas fa-eye'></i>"+
                        "<a class='edit-calender common-font-properties'>View</a>"+
                        "</div>"+
                        "<div class='display-inline-block'>"+
                        " <i class='fas fa-trash'></i>"+
                        " <a class='edit-calender common-font-properties'>Delete</a>"+
                        " </div>"+
                        "</div>";

                                       //$('.fc-content .fc-title', this).wrapAll("<div class='wrapall'><div>");
//                    $('.fc-content .wrapall', this).prepend($template);
                    $('.fc-content', this).prepend($template);
                },

                eventMouseout: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                    //$('#event_'+event.id).remove();
                },
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: [

                    {
                        id: 7,
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: '2018-08-12T12:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 8,
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: '2018-08-13T14:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 9,
                        title: 'Happy Hour',
                        start: '2018-08-14T17:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 10,
                        title: 'Dinner',
                        start: '2018-08-15T20:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 11,
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: '2018-08-16T07:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 12,
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        url: 'http://google.com/',
                        start: '2018-03-28'
                    }
                ]
            });
  </script>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xelajufuqi/edit?html,output)

the problem that i am facing is fairly simple the hover div i am creating sits on back of the box it is not fully visible on smaller screen everything hides, i have tried a dozen of thing trying **z-index** etc but i am still not able to increase the **z-index** or make my div visible. any help?

Comment: You should probably make sure you understand how to spell calendar since it seems you are using an incorrect spelling like half the time. Might have nothing to do with this, but it's gonna introduce a whole bunch of bugs at some point, especially when using a library around said word.

Comment: @Roope my Apologies! i have changed the answer although it might take a while changing the classes, would do that in future.

Answer (score 0):

With your current markup this is not going to work, the child cannot have a z-index greater than the parent, it's set to the same stacking index. You would have to have your hover div outside the markup of the calendar and position it correctly.

Although you could certainly write this yourself, the easiest way to achieve it would be with a library.

Have a look at the Fullcalendar [demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo), it uses the Bootstrap popover functionality. Open your dev tools and hover over an event and you will see that the markup for the tooltip is added below the calendar. If you are not already using Bootstrap another alternative would be [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/download) which is a jQuery plugin, which you will be using with it being a FC dependency.

Example using qTip2:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  defaultView: "basicWeek",
  defaultDate: "2018-04-07",
  resources: [
    { id: "a", title: "Room A" },
    { id: "b", title: "Room B", eventColor: "green" },
    { id: "c", title: "Room C", eventColor: "orange" },
    { id: "d", title: "Room D", eventColor: "red" }
  ],
  events: [
    {
      id: "1",
      resourceId: "a",
      start: "2018-04-06",
      end: "2018-04-08",
      title: "event 1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      resourceId: "a",
      start: "2018-04-07T09:00:00",
      end: "2018-04-07T14:00:00",
      title: "event 2"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      resourceId: "b",
      start: "2018-04-07T12:00:00",
      end: "2018-04-08T06:00:00",
      title: "event 3"
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      resourceId: "c",
      start: "2018-04-07T07:30:00",
      end: "2018-04-07T09:30:00",
      title: "event 4"
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      resourceId: "d",
      start: "2018-04-07T10:00:00",
      end: "2018-04-07T15:00:00",
      title: "event 5"
    }
  ],
  eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.qtip({
      content: {
        title: { text: event.title },
        text:
          '<span class="title">Start: </span>' +
          $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "hh:mmtt") +
          '<br><span class="title">Description: </span>' +
          event.description
      },
      hide: {
        delay: 200,
        fixed: true
      },
      position: {
        target: "mouse", // Use the mouse position as the position origin
        adjust: {
          // Don't continuously  the mouse, just use initial position
          mouse: false
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ally-murray/pen/PBLKOJ?editors=0010) with working qTip2 demo.

Comment: thankyou so much what you said made perfect sense the problem i have is that the hover div i want to show has button and actions which are going to be performed so i need some hover div that stays in the position when its hovered and vanishes when the cursor leaves the area,just like a standard hover div, i have seen this qtip seems nice but it only leaves me with the issue that i need something that stays on hover so i can click on buttons do you have an example of code in qtip? i have seen example in qtip but they are not showing the source, e.g the tooltip with the close button.

Comment: If you are just looking for it to remain open for you to click one of your action buttons, the above demo should allow you to achieve this. You will just have to swap ou the content with your markup. The tool-tip opens and remains open as long as the mouse is over it and then automatically closes when you mouse out.